# hibernate java select queries

Tags: java, hibernate

i am new to this and today i tried to play hibernate with a method that returns the result of selected  row...if is selected then it can return the result in int.. here is my method

```
 public int validateSub(String slave, String source, String table){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();


    Query q = session.createQuery("from Subscribers where slave = :slave AND source = :source AND tbl = :tbl");
    q.setParameter("slave", slave);
    q.setParameter("source", source);
    q.setParameter("tbl", table);

    int result = q.executeUpdate();

    return result;

}
```

from this method i tried to validate the 3 values that i get from the Subscribers table but at the end i tried to compile having this error

```
     Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for select queries [from com.datadistributor.main.Subscribers where slave = :slave AND source = :source AND tbl = :tbl]
```

Comment: Your query is not an insert/update/delete query, so I wouldn't have thought that `executeUpdate` would return anything meaningful.  Also, make sure to commit your transaction, close your session again...

Comment: executeUpdate() returns an int which represents the number of rows affected by the query. As beny23 mentioned, it assumes that you are running a insert/update/modify query. If you just want a count of what was returned, you will have to rewrite your query to return a count.

Comment: is there any possible way to return something like int value from the selected query? i need to return it to validate whether those data from the method parameter exist in the Subscribers table...and i dont think the error above is from my executeUpdate? seems like the select statement is wrong..

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the below links that how **executeUpdate** works, one is from the hibernate docs and other the java docs for JPA which defines when the exception is thrown by the method

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate()

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#executeUpdate()

Alternatively you can use

```
 List list = query.list();    
 int count = list != null ? list.size() : 0;
 return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are running a select query, Eventhough you are not using the select keyword here hibernate will add that as part of the generated SQL.

what you need to do to avoid the exception is the say

```
q.list();
```

now, this will return a List ([here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html) is the documentation).
if you are trying to get the size of the elements you can say

```
    Query q = session.createQuery("select count(s) from Subscribers s where slave = :slave AND source = :source AND tbl = :tbl");
Long countOfRecords = (Long)q.list().get(0);
```

you can execute update statements as well in HQL, it follows a similar structure as SQL (except with object and properties).

Hope this helps.

Comment: q.list().iterate().next().intValue();
having problem with these code above as i am not using the latest hibernate i think...still using version 3.3.2 cause i cant really find support especially in setting up for the hibernate v4...i think v3 does not have iterate() and intvalue()

Comment: appreciate your help but i compiled it and get this error instead which i am not sure what happen Exception in thread     "Thread-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake.. the server will reutrn a long as a result when asked to get count.. i updated my answer again.

Answer (score 1):

here you want to select record so it is posible without select key word

```
sessionFactory sesionfatory;
ArrayList list = (ArrayList)sessionfactory.getCurruntSession().find(from table where name LIKE "xyz");

long size = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also happened to make the same mistake today.
Your SQL statement is not correct.

You can try:

`DELETE from Subscribers WHERE slave = :slave AND source`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int result = q.list().size();
```